# Python: Check for a number in integer

Tags: python, integer

how do you check for a number in an integer for python?  basically a function that returns true if 8 is in the integer.  so function(8291) returns True but function(777) returns false. 
what's is the trick to search for a number?

Answer (score 7):

```
def contains_digit(digit, number):
    return str(digit) in str(number)
```

Comment: FWIW `import string` with a `return string.digits[digit] in str(number)` appears to be roughly 25% faster.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to convert it to string and search there.

`'8' in str(8291)` -> True

`'8' in str(777)` -> False

Answer (score 0):

Python's got a method for this if you convert it to a string.

```
def function(number_to_search):
    return '8' in str(number_to_search)
```